# Jquery links good practice

Tags: jquery

Have this

```
<a href="#">something</a>
```

and then I handle it in Jquery code. This displays the # in browser status bar when hover. Is this a good practice for production, other alternatives?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even have to define the href attribute. Usually I will just code like this:

```
<a onclick="...">Link</a>
```

or

```
$('#blah').click(function(){...});
...
<a id="blah">Link</a>
```

Check the specifications:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-xhtml2-20030506/mod-hypertext.html

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-A

There are more I'm sure but I suppose it really depends on the doctype you're using. Anyway long story short it's not bad practice to not specify the href attribute and a validator should pass it. And yeah... # in the address bar always looks messy to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to stop links from redirecting the page:

HTML:

```
<a href="http://disneyland.com/">Let's go to DisneyLand!</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
//jQuery passes in the event object as e
e.preventDefault();
alert("LOL, you really thought you were going?");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrXAs/

Comment: event.preventDefault is a native built-in method of `event` object. it has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: I know, I meant how jQuery passes the event parameter and you can use that in jQuery to stop the default action. Poor writing on my part, editing...

Comment: I've included it in my answer. sadly, someone -1'd it for unknown reasons. :>

Answer (score -1):

Hash sign appearing in the url isn't really that wrong, but the other effect you may notice is your page being scrolled to it's top after clicking a link.

To fix that, in the function which responds to your event you should use `event.preventDefault()` (assuming you're catching `event` parameter):

```
$(element).click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // your code...
})
```

or use `return false`:

```
$(element).click( function(event) {
    // your code...
    return false;
})
```

Comment: Don't forget `window.event.returnValue = false` for IE < 9. +1 for `return false`.