# It is wrong or a bad practice to use "javascript://" as links to prevent action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I just saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439873/jquery-links-good-practice) 
and it reminds me of something I usually do to prevent the default action of some link:

```
<a href="javascript://">something</a>
```

Then I handle it with jQuery click function. I already saw in some places people using

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">something</a>
```

I know the better way is using

```
e.preventDefault();
```

But is it wrong or a bad practice to do what I do? How this actually works?

Comment: One related tidbit: in the values of "onfoo" event handler attributes, a "javascript:" prefix means absolutely nothing to the browser, and it ends up being interpreted as a statement label to the JavaScript parser.

Comment: If you want to use the click, but not the link consider using <button>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is bad practice because a better mechanism exists and that is `event.preventDefault()`.

Also, the `javascript:` pseudo protocol should only be used for bookmarklets.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit unfortunate because if the user Ctrl+clicks or right clicks and says "Open in New Tab," they will get a completely blank page.

Using `<a href="#">something</a>` plus `preventDefault` is better, since in that case Ctrl+click just takes them back to the page they were on.

Of course, the very best is if you can have the `href` point to a page that is actually meaningful, with the JavaScript being a progressive enhancement to the experience that overrides that meaningful default. A great example of this is popup windows, but with a bit more work anything can be made to do this.